# When assigning pointers, what is the difference between a memcpy and just assigning?

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

For example, I have the following pointers:

```
char *ptr;
char *string;

string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
//set string to some word
```

What is the difference between the following lines ?

```
ptr = string;

vs.

memcpy(ptr, string, sizeof(string));
```

Also, will there be issues if I tried to free "string" after either of these assignments? Would "ptr" still retain the value I assigned it to?

Comment: It's the difference between pointer and pointee.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the difference between the following lines ?
>
> ```
> ptr = string;
> ```
>
> vs.
>
> ```
> memcpy(ptr, string, sizeof(string));
> ```

The former assigns variable `ptr` to point to the same location that `string` points to.  The latter attempts to copy `sizeof(string)` bytes from the location `string` *points to* to the location `ptr` points to.  If, however, `ptr` has not been initialized to point to a block of memory large enough to contain that many bytes, or if it has not been initialized at all, then the behavior is undefined.

Note, too, that `sizeof(string)` is not ordinarily the number of bytes you want when `string` is of type `char *`.  You might want `strlen(string) + 1` instead, or you might want whatever the size is of the memory block `string` points to (10 in this case).  But `sizeof(string)` is the size of a pointer, which is the same for any pointer to the same type -- probably either 4 or 8 bytes, depending on your implementation.

> Also, will there be issues if I tried to free "string" after either of
>   these assignments? Would "ptr" still retain the value I assigned it
>   to?

After `ptr = string`, the two variables point to the same block of memory.  There is no inherent problem with freeing that memory, which you can do via either pointer, but you must not thereafter attempt to dereference either pointer until you assign a new value to it that points to an accessible piece of memory.

After the `memcpy()`, on the other hand, if the behavior is defined at all (see above) then each pointer points to a separate copy of the same data.  Freeing one of them frees only that copy -- in that case it is still ok to dereference the other one.

Answer (score 1):

```
memcpy(ptr, string, sizeof(string));    // but you will need to allocate memory to ptr
```

This will copy number of specified bytes (`4` or `8` bytes as pointed out by @alk Sir ) to memory block pointed by 
`ptr`.

Using `memcpy` memory blocks to which `ptr` and `src` are different.

Whereas , this -

```
ptr = string;
```

in this `ptr` points to *memory block* to which `string` points.

Comment: And "*`sizeof(string)`*" is how much?

Comment: No, as pointers are not arrays. You might like to read the other answer by *John Bollinger* (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32954656/694576), as well as probably this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954433/when-assigning-pointers-what-is-the-difference-between-a-memcpy-and-just-assign/32954477?noredirect=1#comment53735816_32954590 of mine.

Comment: @alk Ohh yes, `sizeof` will see its type not contents  . Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

`ptr = string;` will make `ptr` "point to" the same address as `string`

`memcpy(ptr,string,sizeof(string))` will copy the data stored at the address pointed to by `string` to the address pointed to by `ptr`. `memcpy()` will only copy the number of bytes specified (10 in your example).

The later will result in an error as you've written it since `ptr` is undefined.

to answer the second part of you question. If you do a `memcpy()`, `ptr` will still retain the data copied to it after you `free(string)`. `ptr` will be made invalid in the case of `ptr = string` since they will both point to the same address.

Comment: "*... copy the number of bytes specified (10 in your example).*" no, it either copies 4 or 8 bytes, depending whether run on a 32 or 64 bit-platform. Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: @alk, What I believe was meant is that in the context of normal `char` strings on a normal linux/windows system it will essentially copy `sizeof(string)` bytes starting from the location `string` to the location `ptr`.

Comment: @SamuelAllan: `sizeof x` ***always*** returns the size of the variable `x`, and if `x` is defined to be a pointer (like`char * x;`) then this size typically is 4 or 8 bytes, ***no*** matter what the pointer points to. To find the length of a C-"string" use `strlen()`.

Comment: @alk apparently I misread his code.. yes you are correct. I thought it was `strlen` (actually who knows what I thought I obviously couldn't read)